# How To Handle An InvalidOperationException In A foreach Loop Containing yield return?

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code in which I am trying to take each element returned by an ICollectionView and translate it into a different object.

```
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (TOriginal original in _collectionView)
        {
            if (!Equals(original, null))
            {
                yield return GetTranslated(original);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return default(TTranslated);
            }
        }
    }
```

If _collectionView is changed during the foreach (this is happening in my test app) then it throws an InvalidOperationException, but I can't wrap the foreach loop in a try/catch because VisualStudio complains "'yield return' statement couldn't appear in a try/catch block".

How can I handle the exception?

Comment: Do you actually need to handle the exception? I'd imagine that *not* handling it and letting it bubble up to the caller would be the most obvious behaviour.

Comment: @LukeH that's a good point, maybe I'm looking at the wrong problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumerators aren't required to remain valid if the collection is modified. The standard behavior is that if the collection is modified in the middle of enumeration, the enumerator will throw an InvalidOperationException the next time `MoveNext` is called.

I believe letting the InvalidOperationException propagate is the proper behavior. Your enumerator will have the same semantics as all the standard collection classes, so consumers of your class will expect this.

If consumers of your class need to change the list during iteration, they should loop using an index value, and change the indexer as needed when they modify the list.

Answer (score 1):

The `yield return` can't be in a `try...catch`, but that doesn't mean that you can't catch exceptions while you are getting the value to be returned.

Example:

```
object value;
try {
  value = SomeCodeThatCanBreak();
} catch (SomeException ex) {
  // you could silently skip this item:
  value = null;
}
if (value != null) {
  yield return value;
}
```

If the exception indicates that the collection has changed, you would however exit out of the loop rather than skipping items, as you won't get any more items out of the enumerator.

You would have to decide what action should be appropriate for each exception type that you catch. In some situations it might be logical to silently handle the exceptions, but in most situations you should let the exception bubble up, or throw a different exception if that better describes the problem.